# Subsetting data.table by 2nd column only of a 2 column key, using binary search not vector scan

Tags: r, data.table

I recently discovered binary search in `data.table`. If the table is sorted on multiple keys it possible to search on the 2nd key only ?

```
DT = data.table(x=sample(letters,1e7,T),y=sample(1:25,1e7,T),rnorm(1e7))
setkey(DT,x,y)
#R> DT[J('x')]
#        x  y       V3
#     1: x  1  0.89109
#     2: x  1 -2.01457
#    ---              
#384922: x 25  0.09676
#384923: x 25  0.25168
#R> DT[J('x',3)]
#       x y       V3
#    1: x 3 -0.88165
#    2: x 3  1.51028
#   ---             
#15383: x 3 -1.62218
#15384: x 3 -0.63601
```

EDIT: thanks to @Arun

```
R> system.time(DT[J(unique(x), 25)])
   user  system elapsed 
  0.220   0.068   0.288 
R> system.time(DT[y==25])
   user  system elapsed 
  0.268   0.092   0.359
```

Comment: This is now covered one of the [Getting Started vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) on the `Rdatatable` Github page.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you can pass all values to the first key value and subset with the specific value for the second key.

```
DT[J(unique(x), 25), nomatch=0]
```

If you need to subset by more than one value in the second key (e.g. the equivalent of `DT[y %in% 25:24]`), a more general solution is to use `CJ`

```
DT[CJ(unique(x), 25:24), nomatch=0]
```

[Note](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.datatable/2609/focus=2613) that `CJ` by default sorts the columns and sets key to all the columns, which means the result would be sorted as well.  If that's not desirable, you should use `sorted=FALSE`

```
DT[CJ(unique(x), 25:24, sorted=FALSE), nomatch=0]
```

There's also a feature request to add secondary keys to `data.table` in future. I believe the plan is to add a new function `set2key`.

[FR#1007 Build in secondary keys](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1007&group_id=240&atid=978)

There is also `merge`, which has a method for `data.table`. It builds the secondary key inside it for you, so should be faster than base merge. See `?merge.data.table`.

Comment: thanks, looks a bit inefficient compare t usual data.table performance, though better than R vector search...

Comment: Yes, I can't think of a better way. But I don't think it is intended to be used this way, in general. If you check for example, `DF[DF$x == "a" & DF$y == "25", ]` and `DT[J("a", 25)]` you'll see the difference.

Comment: sure but then you have to sort again... anything if we want `DF[DF$x == "a" | DF$y == "25", ]` (OR instead of AND)

Comment: Now, that's a good question! Why don't you start as another question? I'm sure I'd like to see if that's possible (to implement).

Comment: This is good for now. The goal is to implement secondary keys (`set2key`) to improve both speed and syntax of queries like this.

Comment: @Arun Have edited in the `nomatch=0`.  It's needed, right? Didn't spot that before.

Comment: @MatthewDowle, yes indeed! I've missed that. Just rechecked the documentation. Thanks for correcting.

Comment: @MatthewDowle I don't which method would be actually better (for speed and/or added functionality) but `named columns in J could define the key to use` would be a very hand and powerful option to have, thanks again for your `data.table`!

Comment: @Michele  Hi, yes I'd find that useful too. How best to do it has been thrown around for a while,  we'll get there eventually hopefully ...

Answer (score 6):

Based on [this email thread](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Select-from-second-key-but-not-first-td3663804.html) I wrote the following functions:

```
create_index = function(dt, ..., verbose = getOption("datatable.verbose")) {
  cols = data.table:::getdots()
  res = dt[, cols, with=FALSE]
  res[, i:=1:nrow(dt)]
  setkeyv(res, cols, verbose = verbose)
}

JI = function(index, ...) {
  index[J(...),i]$i
}
```

Here are the results on my system with a larger DT (1e8 rows):

```
> system.time(DT[J("c")])
   user  system elapsed 
  0.168   0.136   0.306 

> system.time(DT[J(unique(x), 25)])
   user  system elapsed 
  2.472   1.508   3.980 
> system.time(DT[y==25])
   user  system elapsed 
  4.532   2.149   6.674 

> system.time(IDX_y <- create_index(DT, y))
   user  system elapsed 
  3.076   2.428   5.503 
> system.time(DT[JI(IDX_y, 25)])
   user  system elapsed 
  0.512   0.320   0.831
```

If you are using the index multiple times it is worth it.

Comment: Thanks. I've extended your function for Nth key: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/804