# Perform an R data.table binary search with OR select

Tags: r, data.table

I'm working with a data.table named "lines", created with 2 binary indexes

```
setkeyv(lines,c("start","end"))
```

I need to perform a fast binary search to find which records in "start" column OR "end" column are equal to a value (or more than one), for example, in SQL it would be something like this:

```
select column1, column2, column3 from lines where start = 2 OR end = 2
```

In R data.tables with binary indexes, I can do somethig like this

`lines[.(2,2)]`

but this sentence is equal to start = 2 AND end = 2, and that is not what I need.

I know that it's possible to do it with something like this, but it's not faster enought, and it does not uses binary searching.

```
line[(start == c(2,3) | end == c(2,3)];
```

What can I do to execute a fast search with this requirements?

A simple example of what I need to do.

```
lines <- data.table(id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), start = c(901,902,903,904,905,906,907), end = c(101,102,103,104,105,106,107));

checklines <- data.table(id = c(1,2,3,4), startcheck = c(330,902,903,101), endcheck = c(106,400,907));

setkeyv(lines, c("start","end");
```

I need to search the records in lines that the value of start OR end are the values ​​of checklines startcheck or endcheck.

What i'm doing now is:

```
lines[start %in% c(checklines$startcheck,checklines$endcheck) | end %in% c(checklines$startcheck,checklines$endcheck)];
```

The result will be:

[image]

But this search is not faster enough, and if i am not wrong, it does not uses the binary keys.

Comment: possible dupe with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597971/can-we-do-binary-search-in-data-table-with-or-select-queries

Comment: Yeah, seems like a dupe to me...oh wait, it's not, since you have both columns with the same type and can melt as in the answer you posted. Btw, I think the general issue of binary search OR queries falls under this multi-part issue: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1453

Answer (score 2):

We can use `%in%` instead of `==`.  `==` is used when there is only a single element to compare or the whole column for elementwise comparison.  When there are multiple elements, use `%in%`

```
line[(start %in% c(2,3) | end %in% c(2,3))];
```

Comment: That is true, thank you. But that code does not perform a binary search, correct? I'm looking for something fast, as binary search, because the data.table contains millions of records.

Comment: @Carlos Can you please provide a small reproducible example for testing

Comment: I have added a simple example in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Testing this example you can check that with %in% clause, if the index is enabled, the performance improvement is remarkable (it uses the binary index)

```
set.seed(108)
N = 1e8
DT = setDT(list(sample(N/10, N, TRUE), sample(letters, N, TRUE)))
setindexv(DT, c("V1","V2"))
options("datatable.use.index"=TRUE)
system.time(ans1<-DT[V1 %in% 1000:1002 & V2 %in% c("a","b","c")])
# user system elapsed
# 0.001 0.000 0.002
options("datatable.use.index"=FALSE)
system.time(ans2<-DT[V1 %in% 1000:1002 & V2 %in% c("a","b","c")])
# user system elapsed
# 4.051 0.848 4.899
```

But, changing **&** with **|**

```
system.time(ans1<-DT[V1 %in% 1000:1002 | V2 %in% c("a","b","c")])
```

it doesn't matter if the index is ON or OFF, 
behaves as if the index was not activated.

Any ideas on how to optimize the performance of this search?

-- EDIT --

I found a solution transforming the search columns (start and end) into rows with the melt function:

```
channelids <<- melt(lines[,c("id","start","end")], id=c("id"));
```

The result is a structure like this:

[image]

Now, including a binary index to the object,

```
setkey(channelids, value);
```

the search is faster and the objects are quite smaller than other methods I have tested.

Answer (score 0):

A few other approaches and timing really depends on your actual dimensions. As mentioned in comment, the dupe runs a query on 1 record multiple times whereas here there is a need to search the dataset for multiple records.

data:

```
#generate sample datasets
library(data.table)
set.seed(0L)
nr <- 1e6
lines <- data.table(start=sample(1:1e4, nr, TRUE), end=sample(1:1e4, nr, TRUE))[, id := .I]
checklines <- unique(data.table(start=sample(1:1000, 1000, TRUE), end=sample(1:1000, 1000, TRUE))[, id := .I])
checks <- c(checklines$start, checklines$end)

DT <- copy(lines)
sl <- copy(lines)  
el <- copy(lines)
```

timing code:

```
bench::mark(
    mtd0={
        setkey(lines, start, end)
        lines[start %in% checks | end %in% checks]
    },
    mtd2={
        setkey(DT, start)
        ix1 <- DT[.(checks), id]
        setkey(DT, end)
        ix2 <- DT[.(checks), id]
        DT[unique(c(ix1, ix2))]
    },
    mtd3={
        setkey(sl, start)
        setkey(el, end)
        lines[unique(c(sl[.(checks), id], el[.(checks), id]))]
    },
    check=FALSE #ordering difference
)
```

timings:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 14
  expression      min     mean   median      max `itr/sec` mem_alloc  n_gc n_itr total_time result                     memory              time    gc              
  <chr>      <bch:tm> <bch:tm> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt> <dbl> <int>   <bch:tm> <list>                     <list>              <list>  <list>          
1 mtd0         36.8ms   37.2ms   37.2ms   37.3ms      26.9    36.9MB     8     5      186ms <data.table [165,061 x 3]> <Rprofmem [19 x 3]> <bch:t~ <tibble [13 x 3~
2 mtd2         49.4ms   51.1ms   50.4ms     57ms      19.6    20.5MB     3     7      358ms <data.table [165,061 x 3]> <Rprofmem [43 x 3]> <bch:t~ <tibble [10 x 3~
3 mtd3         20.8ms   21.7ms   21.4ms   22.8ms      46.1    20.5MB     4    14      303ms <data.table [165,061 x 3]> <Rprofmem [43 x 3]> <bch:t~ <tibble [18 x 3~
```