# Subsetting data.table by not head(key(DT),m), using binary search not vector scan

Tags: r, data.table

If I specify n columns as a key of a `data.table`, I'm aware that I can join to fewer columns than are defined in that key as long as I join to the `head` of `key(DT)`. For example, for n=2 :

```
X = data.table(A=rep(1:5, each=2), B=rep(1:2, each=5), key=c('A','B'))
X
    A B
 1: 1 1
 2: 1 1
 3: 2 1
 4: 2 1
 5: 3 1
 6: 3 2
 7: 4 2
 8: 4 2
 9: 5 2
10: 5 2

X[J(3)]
   A B
1: 3 1
2: 3 2
```

There I only joined to the first column of the 2-column key of `DT`. I know I can join to both columns of the key like this :

```
X[J(3,1)]
   A B
1: 3 1
```

But how do I subset using only the second column colum of the key (e.g. `B==2`), but still using binary search not vector scan?   I'm aware that's a duplicate of :

[Subsetting data.table by 2nd column only of a 2 column key, using binary search not vector scan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597685/data-table-and-binary-search)

so I'd like to generalise this question to `n`. My data set has about a million rows and solution provided in dup question linked above doesn't seem to be optimal.

Comment: It's just `X[B==2,]`. Suggested reading: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.pdf

Comment: @MatthewPlourde, are you sure?  The vignette you reference has the following sentence that makes your solution sound sub-optimal: "We use the key to take advantage of the fact that the table is sorted and use binary search to find the matching rows. We didn't vector scan; we didn't use ==."

Comment: @GSee thanks, you're absolutely right. apologies, my mistake.

Comment: I may have jumped the gun marking this as a duplicate...

Comment: @GSee Seems like a dup to me. The accepted answer to the dup is good but we'd like to do better; e.g. when `set2key` is implemented.

Comment: @MatthewDowle That solution doesn't give the correct result for OP's data.

Comment: Yeah, the solution in the dup's answer does not give correct data.

Comment: @geektrader update your question and I'll flip my downvote. Apologies for the hasty judgement.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde Oh, indeed. It needs a `nomatch=0`. Have edited the dup answer and pinged Arun to check.

Comment: So is this a duplicate or not? If not we can arrange to have it reopened!

Comment: Thanks all for comments and help. I have updated the question. The answer in the linked question doesn't seem to be ideal solution though. Nevertheless, I am ok if the question stays marked duplicate if there is no better solution.

Comment: @geektrader Have you considered contributing improvements to `data.table`?  You would be very welcome.

Comment: @MatthewDowle I am not confident of my programming capabilities from package development point of view, but I can certainly help in testing aspects of this wonderful package :)

Comment: The title and question still doesn't seem right. You can already join to fewer columns than are in the key. What needs to be asked is not only `m<n` but where head(key(DT),m) != columns.

Comment: @MatthewDowle Please feel free to edit the question to make it more appropriate. I am unable to word it properly in subject.

Comment: @MatthewDowle wow... that's so much better wording. :)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple function that will extract the correct unique values and return a data table to use as a key.

```
 X <- data.table(A=rep(1:5, each=4), B=rep(1:4, each=5), 
                  C = letters[1:20], key=c('A','B','C'))
 make.key <- function(ddd, what){
  # the names of the key columns
  zzz <- key(ddd)
  # the key columns you wish to keep all unique values
  whichUnique <- setdiff(zzz, names(what))
  ## unique data.table (when keyed); .. means "look up one level"
  ud <-  lapply([, ..whichUnique], unique)
  ## append the `what` columns and  a Cross Join of the new
  ## key columns
  do.call(CJ, c(ud,what)[zzz])
}   

X[make.key(X, what = list(C = c('a','b'))),nomatch=0]
## A B C
## 1: 1 1 a
## 2: 1 1 b
```

I'm not sure this will be any quicker than a couple of vector scans on a large data.table though.

Answer (score 2):

Adding secondary keys is on the feature request list :

[FR#1007 Build in secondary keys](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1007&group_id=240&atid=978)

In the meantime we are stuck with either vector scan, or the approach used in the answer to the n=2 case linked in the question (which @mnel generalises nicely in his answer).