# select rows in data.table using only the second key

Tags: r, data.table

If I have the following:

```
a<-data.table(id=rep(letters[1:4],2), var=c(1,2,1:6), key="id,var")
```

I can replicate the "usual" `a[a$id=="a" & a$var==1,]` with

```
> a[.("a",1)]
   id var
1:  a   1
```

but what about `a[a$var==1,]`?  If I change `"a"` with the whole `id` column I don't get what I'd expect:

```
> a[.(id,1)]
   id var
1:  a   1
2:  a   1
3:  b   1
4:  b   1
5:  c   1
6:  c   1
7:  d   1
8:  d   1
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Anything wrong with using `a[var == 1,]`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subsetting data.table by 2nd column only of a 2 column key, using binary search not vector scan](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597685/subsetting-data-table-by-2nd-column-only-of-a-2-column-key-using-binary-search).  Alternate possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769837/subsetting-data-table-by-not-headkeydt-m-using-binary-search-not-vector-sca

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
> a[ .(unique(id), 1),, nomatch = 0 ]
   id var
1:  a   1
2:  c   1
```

ADDED. We could avoid having to scan `id` by making it a factor and using the levels:

```
> a<-data.table(id=factor(rep(letters[1:4],2)), var=c(1,2,1:6), key="id,var")
> a[ .(levels(id), 1),, nomatch = 0 ]
   id var
1:  a   1
2:  c   1
```

Comment: it works, thanks. I guess there isn't a more compact way to do that, right?

Comment: Its no more compact but I have added a potentially more efficient alternative

Comment: I see, yeah, I'll probablt be much faster. Thanks again