# Row index for a data.table "binary search" on a subset of columns

Tags: r, data.table

I have a larger set of data and need the **Row numbers** of rows that fulfill certain conditions. Package data.table.

```
days <- strptime(c("2013-01-01 8:00:00", "2013-02-01 8:00:00"), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
DateTime <- rep(seq(days[1], days[2], length.out=1e6/5), 5)
Update <- rep(LETTERS[3:1], length.out=1e6)
Group <- rep(c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC"), length.out=1e6)
Weight <- trunc(rnorm(1e6, 110, 3))
Weight2 <- rnorm(1e6, 100, 1.5)
DT <- data.table(DateTime, Update, Group, Weight, Weight2)
setkey(DT, DateTime, Update, Group, Weight, Weight2)

Exp <- DT[1e6/2]
```

I cannot create another data.table as a subset without the column DateTime since this column is used in the key. Creating a new key on the subset could change the order and I need certainty that the original order is preserved.

It is possible to get the **Row numbers** I need by using the two commands.

```
system.time(DT[, which(DT$Update==Exp$Update & DT$Group==Exp$Group & DT$Weight==Exp$Weight & DT$Weight2==Exp$Weight2)])
system.time(which(DT$Update==Exp$Update & DT$Group==Exp$Group & DT$Weight==Exp$Weight & DT$Weight2==Exp$Weight2))
```

However I need a faster way to do that.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Please avoid telling generality about packages. They just make your question longer and confusing specially when they are wrong. Make it simple, **I have this, I tried this, I get this but I want to get this**.

Comment: I have edited my question. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597685/subsetting-data-table-by-2nd-column-only-of-a-2-column-key-using-binary-search) does provide an answer to a different, but similar question. The solutions are different.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get the **Row number** the following way.

```
which(is.na(DT[list(DT$DateTime, DT$Update, 
DT$Group, DT$Weight, Exp$Weight2), which=TRUE]) == FALSE)
```

However it is 4 times slower than vector search examples from the Question.