# How to define data.table keys for fastest aggregation using multiple keys

Tags: r, performance, data.table, compound-key

I am trying to better understand utilizing keyd `data.table`s. After reading the documentation I think I understand how to speed up subsetting when using one key. For example:

```
DT = data.table(x=rep(c("ad","bd","cd"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:9)
```

Option one:

```
DT[x == "ad"]
```

Option two:

```
setkey(DT,x)
DT["ad"]
```

In this case option one is much slower than option two, because the data.table uses the key to seach more efficiently (using a binary search vs. a vector scan, which I do not understand but I will trust is faster.)

In the case of aggregating on a subset of the data using a by statement, what is the fastest way to define the key? Should I key the column that I am using to subset the data, or the column that defines the groups? For example:

```
setkey(DT,x)
DT[!"bd",sum(v),by=y]
```

or

```
setkey(DT,y)
DT[!"bd",sum(v),by=y]
```

Is there a way to utilize a key for both `x` and `y`?

**EDIT**

Does setting the key to both `x` and `y` perform two vector searches? i.e:

```
setkey(DT,x,y)
```

**EDIT2**

Sorry, what I *meant* to ask was will the call `DT[!"bd",sum(v),by=y]` perform two binary scans when DT is keyed by both x and y?

Comment: perhaps you're looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15597713/817778 - a cautionary note - option one is *faster* than option two, i.e. if all you're doing is a single look-up and don't have a key set yet, a simple vector scan is going to be faster

Comment: @eddi So a vector scan is faster than setting the key then doing the search? In other words I should not set a new key before I do every search on a new column? And I saw the answer you referenced, but I was curious about using one key for the i argument and a different key for the by assignment.

Comment: to answer your edit - `setkey` sorts all the columns (going last to first), and so will at *least* perform `nrows * num_keycols` operations

Comment: @eddi Sorry for all the confusion. I am still getting used to the new vocabulary and am still struggling to understand how to most efficiently use the `data.table` package. I have read the 10 min intro, FAQ, and most of the documentation. I've also been browsing a lot of SO questions, but I am still feeling iffy overall.

Comment: np; re edit2: if the key is `x,y` it will just do one binary search for the `!"bd"` part. There is no binary search involved in the `by` expression afaik (there is a sort there that is sometimes avoided, e.g. if you did `by=x`, but not in this case).

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is not possible to perform two binary scans when the data table DT is keyed by both x and y. Instead I would repeat the keying first on x and then on y as follows:

```
DT = data.table(x=rep(c("ad","bd","cd"),each=3), y=as.character(c(1,3,4)), v=1:9)
setkey(DT,x)
tmp = DT[!"bd"]
setkey(tmp,y)
tmp[!"1",sum(v),by=y]
```