# How to join data.table by one column of multi-column key

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have a data.table with an id column, a date column and a value column. It is keyed by id and then date. I want to extract only certain dates. Is there a way to join on the second column of the key only, ignoring the first?

For example,

```
values <- data.table(id = rep(1:2, each = 10), dates = rep(1:10, 2), values = rep(c(1,NA,NA, NA), 5))
setkey(values, id, dates)

dates <- data.table(id = c(1,5,8))
setkey(dates, id)

# what i want
x <- values$dates %in% dates$id
values[x]
```

Thanks!

Comment: `setkey(values, dates); values[dates]`?

Comment: Yes there's that :) but im trying to avoid re-keying if i dont have to

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you don't want to?

Comment: This should be possible once [secondary keys - FR #1007](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1007&group_id=240&atid=978) is implemented.

Comment: The tables are pretty big, I'd rather not re-key if I don't have to. I thought this was a common operation so I was sure there would be a more elegant way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subsetting data.table by 2nd column only of a 2 column key, using binary search not vector scan](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597685/subsetting-data-table-by-2nd-column-only-of-a-2-column-key-using-binary-search)

Comment: The reason I asked for join and not subsetting is so that I can combine it with roll.

Comment: If you would be interested to join without resorting (resetkey) more then twice (cause mentioned FR by Arun would cover that) then this FR might solve your issue: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/692

Answer (score 1):

```
values <- data.table(id = rep(1:2, each = 10),
                     dates = rep(1:10, 2),
                     values = rep(c(1,NA,NA, NA), 5))
setkey(values, id, dates)

dates <- data.table(dates = c(1,5,8))
setkey(dates, dates)

merge(values, dates, by = "dates", nomatch = 0)
```

Column to join on should have the same name, so I changed 'id' in 'dates' to 'dates'.