# Set display order of data.table `(group, -value.1)` while preserving key `id`

Tags: r, printing, data.table, key

**Is it possible to store the `order` of rows in a `data.table` while preserving its keys?**

Lets say I have the following dummy table:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(id=letters[1:6], 
                   group=sample(c("red", "blue"), replace=TRUE), 
                   value.1=rnorm(6), 
                   value.2=runif(6))
setkey(dt, id)
dt
   id group    value.1    value.2
1:  a  blue  1.4557851 0.73249612
2:  b   red -0.6443284 0.49924102
3:  c  blue -1.5531374 0.72977197
4:  d   red -1.5977095 0.08033604
5:  e  blue  1.8050975 0.43553048
6:  f   red -0.4816474 0.23658045
```

I would like to store this table so that rows are ordered by `group`, and by `value.1` in decreasing order, i.e:

```
> dt[order(group, value.1, decreasing=T),]
   id group    value.1    value.2
1:  f   red -0.4816474 0.23658045
2:  b   red -0.6443284 0.49924102
3:  d   red -1.5977095 0.08033604
4:  e  blue  1.8050975 0.43553048
5:  a  blue  1.4557851 0.73249612
6:  c  blue -1.5531374 0.72977197
```

Obviously I can save this as a new variable, but I also want to keep the `id` column as my primary key.

Arun's answer to ["What is the purpose of setting a key in data.table?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20057411/2341679) suggests that this can be achieved with clever use `setkey`, since it orders the data.table in the order of its keys (although there is no option to set the key to decreasing order):

```
> setkey(dt, group, value.1, id)
> dt
   id group    value.1    value.2
1:  c  blue -1.5531374 0.72977197
2:  a  blue  1.4557851 0.73249612
3:  e  blue  1.8050975 0.43553048
4:  d   red -1.5977095 0.08033604
5:  b   red -0.6443284 0.49924102
6:  f   red -0.4816474 0.23658045
```

However, I lose the ability to use `id` as my primary key, because `group` is the first key provided:

```
> dt["a"]
   group id value.1 value.2
1:     a NA      NA      NA
```

Comment: Not an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597685/subsetting-data-table-by-2nd-column-only-of-a-2-column-key-using-binary-search/15597713, however I think this will only be possible when [FR#1007](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1007&group_id=240&atid=978) is implemented (secondary keys)

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding it right, but this example doesn't really need sorting in decreasing order, isn't it? All values in `id` are unique...

Comment: @mnel I did try to follow that chain of questions, but it wasn't clear to me whether secondary keys would have the same issue.

Comment: @Arun I want to sort by `value.1` within each group, but want to keep `id` as the primary key. Does that make sense?

Comment: @ScottRitchie, yes. Thanks. Could you elaborate a bit on the type of problem for which you're requiring this (subset based on different keys)?

Comment: It's mostly aesthetic. I'm looking at some group of genes, and I'm ranking them within each group by network connectivity, so it's useful for me to be able to quickly see the `data.table` in that order when talking to my supervisor and collaborators.

Comment: Essentially, I want the `data.table` to behave exactly like `dt; setkey(dt, id)`, but for `show`/`print` to behave as if I'd called `dt[order(group, value.1, decreasing=TRUE)]`. My solution at the moment is to save two tables: one which is keyed, and one which is stored in the order I want.

Comment: It is not obvious from your question should the `id` be the primary key. If not, you can still search the table by `id` even `id` is not a key: `dt[id == "a"]`

Comment: A workaround to get decreasing order is to negate the key field: `dt[, Col := -Col]`

Comment: @mnel: FR#1007 on R-forge is no longer accessible to us, but since dt project has moved to github I assume it was implemented, can you confirm? (and provide updated link)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on @eddi's answer, I've created a hackish solution where I store an unevaluated call to `order` as an attribute of the `data.table`, which `print.data.table` obeys:

```
set_order <- function(dt, cols, decreasing=FALSE) {
  # Store a call to order as an additional attribute
  attr(dt, "order") <- paste0("order(", paste(cols, collapse=", "), 
                              ", decreasing=", decreasing, ")")
  invisible(dt)
}

print.data.table = function(x, ...) {
  if (!is.null(attr(x, "order"))) {
    # Use the stored ordering to print the data.table
    data.table:::print.data.table(x[eval(parse(text=attr(x, "order")))], ...)
  } else {
    data.table:::print.data.table(x, ...)
  }
}
```

Giving me the behaviour I want:

```
dt <- set_order(dt, c("group", "value.1"), decreasing=T)
dt
#    id group    value.1    value.2
# 1:  f   red -0.4816474 0.23658045
# 2:  b   red -0.6443284 0.49924102
# 3:  d   red -1.5977095 0.08033604
# 4:  e  blue  1.8050975 0.43553048
# 5:  a  blue  1.4557851 0.73249612
# 6:  c  blue -1.5531374 0.72977197

tables()
#      NAME NROW MB COLS                     KEY
# [1,] dt      6 1  id,group,value.1,value.2 id 
# Total: 1MB
```

Comment: I noticed data.tables have a `"sorted"` attributed, however changing this doesn't affect the order the table is printed in.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you simply want to modify `print.data.table`:

```
print.data.table = function(x, ...) {
  # put whatever condition identifies your tables here
  if ("group" %in% names(x) && "value.1" %in% names(x)) {
    data.table:::print.data.table(x[order(group, value.1, decreasing = T)], ...)
  } else {
    data.table:::print.data.table(x, ...)
  }
}

set.seed(2)
dt = data.table(id=letters[1:6], 
               group=sample(c("red", "blue"), replace=TRUE), 
               value.1=rnorm(6), 
               value.2=runif(6))
setkey(dt, id)
dt
#   id group     value.1    value.2
#1:  a   red  0.18484918 0.40528218
#2:  e   red  0.13242028 0.44480923
#3:  c   red -1.13037567 0.97639849
#4:  b  blue  1.58784533 0.85354845
#5:  f  blue  0.70795473 0.07497942
#6:  d  blue -0.08025176 0.22582546

dt["c"]
#   id group   value.1   value.2
#1:  c   red -1.130376 0.9763985
```

Comment: I was hoping there would be an inbuilt solution, but good idea to modify `print.data.table`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can still search by id *only*, as follows:

```
dt[J(unique(group),unique(value.1),"a"), nomatch=0]
   group   value.1 id   value.2
1:  blue 0.4928595  a 0.3311728
```

from what I gathered unique(column_name) is the way to include all values for that column.

I am not sure if this helps.

Comment: I get an empty table when I try that.