# What's the fastest way to subset a data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

It seems to me the fastest way to do a row/col subset of a `data.table` is to use the join and `nomatch` option.

Is this correct?

```
DT = data.table(rep(1:100, 100000), rep(1:10, 1000000))
setkey(DT, V1, V2)
system.time(DT[J(22,2), nomatch=0L])
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.00    0.00    0.01 
system.time(subset(DT, (V1==22) & (V2==2)))
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.45    0.21    0.67 

identical(DT[J(22,2), nomatch=0L],subset(DT, (V1==22) & (V2==2)))
# [1] TRUE
```

I also have one problem with the fast join based on binary search: I cannot find a way to select all items in one dimension.

Say if I want to subsequently do:

```
DT[J(22,2), nomatch=0]  # subset on TWO dimensions
DT[J(22,), nomatch=0]   # subset on ONE dimension only
# Error in list(22, ) : argument 2 is empty
```

without having to re-set the key to only one dimension (because I am in a loop and I don't want to rest the keys every time).

Comment: There is good documentation of timings of common data.table operations (including subsetting) here: http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-timings.pdf

Comment: I looked at the doc paragraph 1.1 Extraction. It seems to me the extraction is not exactly subsetting unless one adds the nomatch option. Also this does not address the simulataneous 1 and 2-dimensional subsetting (see my update in question).

Comment: @tucson These are two completely separate questions that require different answers, so they should probably have their own posts, but no matter. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597685/subsetting-data-table-by-2nd-column-only-of-a-2-column-key-using-binary-search for a solution to your second question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### What's the fastest way to subset a `data.table`?

Using the binary search based subset feature is the fastest. Note that the subset requires the option `nomatch = 0L` so as to return only the matching results.

#### How to subset by one of the keys only with two keys set?

If you've two keys set on `DT` and you want to *subset* by the *first key*, then you can just provide the first value in `J(.)`, no need to provide anything for the 2nd key. That is:

```
# will return all columns where the first key column matches 22
DT[J(22), nomatch=0L]
```

If instead, you would like to subset by the *second key*, then you'll have to, as of now, provide all the unique values for the first key. That is:

```
# will return all columns where 2nd key column matches 2
DT[J(unique(V1), 2), nomatch=0L]
```

This is also shown [in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597685/subsetting-data-table-by-2nd-column-only-of-a-2-column-key-using-binary-search). Although I'd prefer that `DT[J(, 2)]` to work for this case, as that seems rather intuitive.

There's also a pending feature request, [FR #1007](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1007&group_id=240&atid=978) for implementing secondary keys, which when done would take care of this.

Here is a better example:

```
DT = data.table(c(1,2,3,4,5), c(2,3,2,3,2))
DT
#    V1 V2
# 1:  1  2
# 2:  2  3
# 3:  3  2
# 4:  4  3
# 5:  5  2
setkey(DT,V1,V2)
DT[J(unique(V1),2)]
#    V1 V2
# 1:  1  2
# 2:  2  2
# 3:  3  2
# 4:  4  2
# 5:  5  2
DT[J(unique(V1),2), nomatch=0L]
#    V1 V2
# 1:  1  2
# 2:  3  2
# 3:  5  2
DT[J(3), nomatch=0L]
#    V1 V2
# 1:  3  2
```

In summary:

```
# key(DT) = c("V1", "V2")

# data.frame                        |             data.table equivalent
# =====================================================================
# subset(DF, (V1 == 3) & (V2 == 2)) |            DT[J(3,2), nomatch=0L]
# subset(DF, (V1 == 3))             |              DT[J(3), nomatch=0L]
# subset(DF, (V2 == 2))             |  DT[J(unique(V1), 2), nomatch=0L]
```

Comment: an important caveat to keep in mind is that for a single subset `DT[V1 == 3 & V2 == 2]` is going to be faster than setting the key and doing a binary search - so binary search only makes sense if the key is already set or you do multiple searches per `setkey`