# Automating the subset command in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, dt, microbenchmark

the given script subsets the iris data in R based on the given condition. However, when the same is applied on very large data say 10 million+, the solution goes for a toss. Please help me with a faster way of achieving the same result in less time. Thanks.

```
iris1 <- subset(iris,iris$Sepal.Length<=5 & iris$Sepal.Length >= 3)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23755839/whats-the-fastest-way-to-subset-a-data-table, I saw this post, but am not able to tweak my code in the same way. Kindly suggest.

Comment: @www, I need assistance with this question, please help me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48385417/automating-selectinput-and-menuitems-in-r-shiny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `data.table` already?

A standard way to do this would be:

```
library(data.table)
iris <- iris
setDT(iris)
# you could try here "setkey(iris, Sepal.Length)" but shouldn't matter
iris1 <- iris[Sepal.Length %between% c(3, 5)]
```

Comment: thanks a lot for replying, my concern is that will this approach process a data of size say 10M better than the common subset function? Kindly suggest.

Comment: Usually `data.table` is way faster than base `R`. Why not experiment?

Comment: @snoram Thanks for showing the use of `%between%` syntax. I followed your code example and conducted a benchmarking, and `data.table` is the fastest.

Answer (score 2):

I have conducted the following benchmarking to compare the subset using three difference approaches: the `subset` function from base R, the `dplyr`, and the `data.table` based on an example data frame with 10000050 rows. The result shows that `data.table` is the fastest.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

# Create example data frame with 10000050 rows
dat <- iris[rep(1:150, times = 66667), ]

# Create example tibble
dat_tbl <- as_tibble(dat)

# Create example data.table
dat_dt <- as.data.table(dat)

# Conduct benchmarking
per <- microbenchmark(# Method 1: The base R subset function
                      m1 = {subset(dat, Sepal.Length <= 5 & Sepal.Length >= 3)},
                      # Method 2: The dplyr method
                      m2 = {dat_tbl %>% filter(Sepal.Length <= 5, Sepal.Length >= 3)},
                      # Method 3: The data.table method
                      m3 = {dat_dt[Sepal.Length %between% c(3, 5), ]}, times = 1000L)

per
# Unit: milliseconds
# expr       min        lq     mean    median        uq      max neval
#   m1 381.17382 776.68467 961.2284 849.74441 1144.4295 2384.084  1000
#   m2 115.79736 137.92646 295.3928 146.91114  511.5023 1452.713  1000
#   m3  50.05212  63.57618 201.6751  70.98142  413.5645 1227.321  1000

# Plot the result
library(ggplot2)
autoplot(per)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, did you try `setkey(iris, Sepal.Length)` also? I think I read somewhere it shouldn't matter in newer versions of `data.table`, but maybe worth the try.

Comment: @snoram Thanks for your call comment. I did not do that but like you said it may be worthy of a try.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to subset a data frame is definitely to convert it to a data table using the -data.table- package.

```
# Load -data.table- package
library(data.table)

# Convert iris to a data table
dt <- as.data.table(iris)

# Subset data table using conditions on Sepal.Length
dt1 <- dt[Sepal.Length<=5 & Sepal.Length >= 3]
```

Comment: `iris` is a built-in data frame in R. You don't have to create a new data frame called `iris` to demonstrate this.