# Performing a semi-anti-join (in binary search)

Tags: r, data.table, anti-join, semi-join

I'd like to subset a `data.table` by *choosing* the first key and *excluding* the second key.

```
set.seed(18032)
DT <- data.table(grp1 = sample(10, 1000, T),
                 grp2 = sample(10, 1000, T),
                 v = rnorm(100), key = "grp1,grp2")
```

My first instinct didn't work (`!` operated too early):

```
DT[.(10, !10)] #!10 = 0, chooses the (10,0) subset
```

This seems too inelegant, but works:

```
DT[.(10, setdiff(unique(grp2), 10))] #unique(grp2) %\% 10 for the bold ;-)
```

And this also works, but this approach sacrifices some functionality (e.g., access to `:=` on `DT`):

```
setkey(DT, grp2, grp1)
DT[!.(10)][CJ(grp2, 10, unique = TRUE)]
#equivalently
DT[!.(10)][.(unique(grp2), 10)]
```

Have I exhausted my options, or am I missing something?

Comment: What is the "(10,0) subset". There are no 0's

Comment: @42- indeed, it returns something because `nomatch = NA`. Would have returned a 0-row table if we set `nomatch = 0`.

Comment: It should be faster to first subset the value of `==` filter, and then `!=`, just be reducing - potentially heavily - the row number of data.

Comment: I guess [this is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597685/subsetting-data-table-by-2nd-column-only-of-a-2-column-key-using-binary-search) somewhat related.

Comment: The `.()` syntax has to conform to `list()`, since it's converted to a data.table.  I don't have much thoughts on how to go about it. Perhaps auto indexing extension could help these cases.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to do what I expected:

```
DT[ grp1==10 & grp2 != 10, ]
```

It seems to allow targeted assignment if you use `:=` in the j -position.

As an example, this should succeed (with no loss of efficiency):

```
 DT[ grp1==10 & grp2 != 10, v := 0 ]
```

Comment: Is there any downside to this not directly accessing the key values? I've no idea, but thought it might be worth noting.

Comment: This is another option, but I believe (?) it fails to take advantage of binary sorting

Comment: Actually some benchmarking suggests they're comparable in speed... I guess this is auto-indexing at work (?)

Comment: I'm not a master of data.table methods, but I _thought_ that this was teh original method for proper selection and assignment.

Comment: splitting into two `[` calls can give speed up as you can utilize key for `grp1==10`, and perform second subset on small dataset

Comment: My point was that you could do an assignment in the j-argument while doing a selection in the i-argument

Comment: @jangorecki it depends on the data size I guess, as `[.data.table` creates an additional (unnecessary) copy. Btw, when working with an integer column, it is better explicitly compare against integers in order to avoid the conversion afterwards, so this should be `DT[ grp1==10L & grp2 != 10L]`

Comment: And no, this solution doesn't use the `bmerge`. This can be easily validated by running `options(datatable.verbose = TRUE)` in the line before.